# Mac App: Storing Information w/ Document-based Applications

Tags: objective-c, macos, filesystems, app-store

I'm in the process of planning out the infrastructure for a Mac App, and we have a startup screen with many user files listed. We want the App to be iCloud-compatible (thus the need for Document-based (key-value won't cut it since they aren't nested - correct me if I'm wrong here)). Essentially, we don't want to have the user keep track of each individual file themselves as that would be irritating, but rather store it in the App's folder until the user needs it (i.e. Email, Export, etc). It would eliminate a lot of the friction in the app, we think. I guess my question is:

- Is it possible to store files automatically in the App's installation folder (or somewhere locally?) without bothering the user - in a Document-based app - and still be App Store compatible? Seems like the ideal solution - user opens app, App knows it's save location and automatically saves documents there when a user creates one, and pulls them to share if needed. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You won't want to store document's in the application's installation folder. For one thing that'll violate the App Store rules, but it's bad behavior anyway, since Applications are normally installed in /Applications, which shouldn't be cluttered up with other files. So storing things in ~/Library/Application Support/YourAppName is the way to go.

To actually implement this, take a look at NSDocumentController and NSDocument itself. You'll basically want to override/modify any UI that allows users to choose a location to save/open documents. Instead, just let them name the documents, and then automatically save them with the given name in the app support folder. Then create a UI that allows them to browse and open those files within the app.